# Show that a periodic function $f(t)$ with period $T$ can be written as $ f(t) = f_T (t) \star \frac{1}{T} \text{comb}\bigg(\frac{t}{T}\bigg) $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, periodic-functions, image-processing

I'm posting this for a friend of mine. We're not sure how to begin with the following problem.

> Show that a periodic function $f(t)$ with period $T$ can be written as 
>   $$ f(t) = f_T (t) \star \frac{1}{T} \text{comb}\bigg(\frac{t}{T}\bigg) $$
>   where $f_T (t)$ is one period of $f(t)$.

The book defines the Fourier series representation as $$ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(2\pi i n \frac{t}{T}) $$
I believe this plays a role in the problem, but I'm not sure where to begin with it. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Write out the comb function as a sum of delta functions, convolve them with $f_T$ one at a time, and then add all of them together.